# clickable icons in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am having some trouble understanding the pattern here. I have a view  and an adaptor mixed in too much. Where is my logic going wrong ?

Trying to get the icons similar to clickable markers. If checked set to true and if checked again back to false.
However even if it is set to true / or false the view doesn't refresh automatically.

```
public class MyPojo {

String title;
String desc;
int image;
boolean isChecked;
```

My Adaptor Class ~

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    TextView title =  (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView desc =  (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final ImageView image =  (ImageView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            title.setText(pojos.get(position).getTitle());
            desc.setText(pojos.get(position).getDesc());
    if (!(pojos.get(position).isChecked())) {
        image.setImageResource(pojos.get(position).getImage());
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            //todo Where do I set my is clicked ?
            if (pojos.get(position).isChecked) {
                pojos.get(position).setChecked(false);
                //image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            }else{
                pojos.get(position).setChecked(true);
                //image.setImageResource(pojos.get(position).getImage());


            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You must bind your views such title and desc in your ViewHolder class not in onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `setOnclickListener()` in `ViewHolder` class instead of `onBindViewHolder()`